# Android Java: How do I update an object inside a method?

Tags: java, android

So a friend and I have been working on a basic android app. We've got the logic blocked out and pseudo-coded, but we're having some trouble updating one of our objects. (BTW, we're still both new to this, so if my terminology is incorrect, I apologize, and corrections would be welcome.) From what I understand, the btcCurrent should update in the dataGet method. I would think this value change would persist, but when I go to set the textView, btcCurrent.last_price is apparently null, not the value it was set to. Debugging in Android Studio has shown that the value is set correctly while in dataGet, but doesn't persist outside it. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.twodudesdev.bitcoinalert;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    TextView textView;
    BitCoinInfo btcCurrent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        textView = this.findViewById(R.id.textDisplayPrice);
        dataGet(client);
        textView.setText(btcCurrent.last_price);
    }

    private void dataGet(AsyncHttpClient client) {
        client.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/btcusd", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
                String toastText = "Successfully downloaded JSON File";
                Toast successfulJsonToast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                successfulJsonToast.show();
                Gson btcGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                btcCurrent = btcGson.fromJson(response, BitCoinInfo.class);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable throwable) {
                String toastText = "Cannot load JSON File: " + throwable;
                Toast failedJsonToast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                failedJsonToast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**BitCoinInfo.java**

```
package com.twodudesdev.bitcoinalert;

public class BitCoinInfo {
    public int id;
    public String mid;
    public String bid;
    public String ask;
    public String last_price;
    public String timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Was does the JSON response you get back look like?

Comment: just a note, naming the method getData would be more conventional than dataGet. dataGet really sounds weird

Comment: @csmckelvey, the JSON was coming through fine, visible at the address in the code, and was being processed properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
    dataGet(client);
    textView.setText(btcCurrent.last_price);
```

You are trying to update your textview text right after making an asynchronous http call, so btcCurrent.last_price is null at that time. Move this line `textView.setText(btcCurrent.last_price);` to `onSuccess` method.

Comment: This did it exactly, even though I could've sworn I'd already done that. Thank you!